# How to pin point the stock maximum of a week

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an operational table, the stock is always in motion. Pallets are booked in, moved between locations and in the end booked off.

This table is very big, around 200.000 records. Due to different contracts, there are different ways to invoice the stock. 
Therefore I created a SCD table, which only keeps track of all the pallets. The SCD is updated every 5 minutes.

The table could be filled like:

```
RecordID PalletID Colli Owner    FromDate         TillDate         Active
       1        1   100 ClientB  01-05-2015 08:15 07-05-2015 16:30     No
       2        2   100 ClientA  01-05-2015 08:15 03-05-2015 10:50     No
       3        3   100 ClientC  01-05-2015 08:15 31-12-2050 00:00    Yes
       4        4   100 ClientA  01-05-2015 08:15 07-05-2015 16:30     No
       5        2    70 ClientA  03-05-2015 10:50 09-05-2015 12:05     No
       6        1    50 ClientB  07-05-2015 16:30 08-05-2015 07:10     No
       7        4    10 ClientA  07-05-2015 16:30 31-12-2015 00:00    Yes
       8        5   250 ClientB  08-05-2015 07:25 31-12-2015 00:00    Yes
```

My problem is: How can I determine, over a week time (for example 04-05-2015 - 10-05-2015), which moment had the biggest amount of colli for a specific client, or the biggest amount of pallets (1 PalletID = 1 pallet)?

In time-table form, it would look like this:

```
   1-5-2015 2-5-2015 3-5-2015 4-5-2015 5-5-2015 6-5-2015 7-5-2015 8-5-2015 9-5-2015 10-5-2015 11-5-2015 12-5-2015 
1       100      100      100      100      100      100      100       50          
2       100      100      100       70       70       70       70       70       70         
3       100      100      100      100      100      100      100      100      100       100       100       100
4       100      100      100      100      100      100      100       10       10        10        10        10
5                                                                      250      250       250       250       250

Pallets   4        4        4        4        4        4        4        5        4         3         3         3
Colli   400      400      400      370      370      370      370      480      430       360       360       360
```

As you can see, 8-5-2015 is the day with the highest stock, in pallets (5) and in colli (480). How can I get this result out of my table?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum by using the following approach.  Take each date/time and give it a number:  +1 for booked in, -1 for booked out.  Then do a cumulative sum and take the maximum:

```
select top 1 dte, sum(inc) over (order by dte) as pallets_in_use
from ((select fromDate as dte, 1 as inc
       from scd
      ) union all
      (select todate, -1
       from scd
      )
     ) s
order by pallets_in_use desc;
```

The only possible issue with this are ties in the `datetime` columns.  However, you would have to specify what happens when there are exact matches on the date/time -- which is unlikely if you are using the built-in `datetime` data types.

Note:  cumulative sum is available in SQL Server 2012+.  If you are using earlier versions, you can do the cumulative sum in other ways.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008:

```
with dates as (
      (select fromDate as dte, 1 as inc
             from scd
      ) union all
      (select todate, -1
       from scd
      )
     )
select top 1 d.dte, d2.pallets_in_use
from dates d outer apply
     (select sum(d2.inc) as pallets_in_use
      from dates d2
      where d2.dte <= d.dte
     ) d2(pallets_in_use)
order by pallets_in_use desc;
```

Comment: What does it look like for SQL Server 2008?
There are no ties, it's a 5 minute cycle, where a pallet can only be present (or not).
For date/time X, the Where clause would be:
    `where fromDate <= X
     and todate > X`

Comment: This query does not give me the date of the highest stock. It gives me the date of oldest pallet on stock.

Comment: @PSVSupporter . . . Oops.  The subquery had `sum(d.inc)` rather than `sum(d2.inc)`.